# Check if array exists in another array with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Is it possible to check if an array

```
A=[
  "EMPRESA",
  "CD_MAQ",
  "DT_INI_MAQ"
]
```

Exists in another array

```
B=[
  "EMPRESA",
  "CD_MAQ",
  "DT_INI_MAQ",
  "CD_WKC",
  "DT_INI_WKC"
]
```

I want to check if all entries in array A exists in B

Comment: To match, must the order be the same, and with no gaps?

Comment: You could just check if the [**intersection**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#intersection) of the two arrays are of equal length to array A: `var completeIntersect = _.intersection(A, B).length === A.length;`

Comment: no order, just if entries of first exist in second

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```js
var A=[
  "EMPRESA",
  "CD_MAQ",
  "DT_INI_MAQ"
];

var B=[
  "EMPRESA",
  "CD_MAQ",
  "DT_INI_MAQ",
  "CD_WKC",
  "DT_INI_WKC"
];

if ( _.difference(A,B).length === 0){
  // all A entries are into B
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Just use `_.difference`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the intersection of the 2 arrays, and then compare to the original.

```js
var A=[
  "EMPRESA",
  "CD_MAQ",
  "DT_INI_MAQ"
];

var B=[
  "EMPRESA",
  "CD_MAQ",
  "DT_INI_MAQ",
  "CD_WKC",
  "DT_INI_WKC"
];

console.log(_.isEqual(_.intersection(B,A), A));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need lodash in this case. Here's one liner with vanilla JS.

```js
A.every(i => B.includes(i))
```

Comment: Elegant, thanks for sharing. The OP requests a solution using Lodash, so technically this doesn't fit the requirement, but this is an elegant solution that removes the requirement to use Lodash (for the better).

Comment: @BrockKlein FYI Lodash is heavily optimized and will be faster than the code given. It also has negligible impact on bundle size if you import the functions you use individually so that the rest can be tree shook.